# Android Studio- git Clone: "Unable to create destination directory"

Tags: android-studio, github

I am trying to clone a github repository from my account in my Android studio, but each time I try to clone it by
`VCS -> get from version control -> URL`,  an error message pops up with message:

> "Clone: Unable to create destination directory".

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to your Android Studio installation directory (usually Program Files/Android/Android Studio).
2. Go to the bin folder.
3. Right click studio64.exe (or studio.exe if you're using the 32bit
   version) and run it as an administrator.
4. Now clone should work just fine.

I'm sure there is a better solution out there but right now, this should work.

Comment: what is the solution for mac os?

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder path.
In my case, my directory name had whitespace, so I changed the folder name from `namu nikam` to `namunikam`.
After that, github cloned the project.
The project error message was:

> Cmd doesn't allow us to run commands with any space in between

Sometimes we use underscores between words, like `namu_nikam`.

Comment: Remember, as per SO guidelines, Capitalization, spelling, and grammar are important. Please edit accordingly to avoid down votes. You can read more about this requirement in the help section of this website. Low quality answers are often downvoted, and sometimes even removed by the platform.